# Bootstrap Columns wrapping at 12

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In my bootstrap project, I'm defining exactly 12 columns in a row (two containers at 6 columns each), but the last container always wraps.

This should work:

```
<div class="process-container">
            <div class="container">
                <section class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h2>Our Focus Is Your Path To Growth</h2>
                        <p>Ommodis quasita testioreri totassita verum ratenda coremporibus idit evelessum a initatur? Quis debis prestrum il es adit quatur resti volut quam, temporio. Nam, qui volor sandi consequi beaque por ma nieneca ra borempo. Ro con ne experitas iliatiis quas ve ra porerum sinvernate minctum rem.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h2></h2>
                        <img src="i/process-graphic.svg" alt="" height="" width="">
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="row">...</section>
             </div>
 </div>
```

But my result is two stacked 6 column elements

Outside of 6 + 6 not actually being 12, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You don't have col-*-12 specified anywhere and even so, two col-md-6 inside a row will always wrap; you need to use col-xs-* if you want the columns to not stack on the smallest viewport (if that's what you are trying to do). http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Comment: My problem is that they are wrapping regardless of viewport width. At 2000px wide, they're still wrapping.

Comment: Post a working demonstration of the problem here in a StackSnippet because I don't see that with the above code.